# Launch printer from the app

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am working on a UWP project and I am trying to print an image from my app. I have tried using the printing sample from microsoft but it's utterly confusing and it's stuck on an error I don't have the time or the patience to solve. Is there a way to launch printer programmatically as if I right clicked the item and chose print?

Comment: if you don't have the time or patience to solve it then who would have time and patience to solve your thread without any error messages given for people to help? how are you supposed to learn?

Comment: After 4 sleepless days of trying to fix them I don't care for it. I don't expect people to solve my errors and bugs, I ask in case someone has already done such a thing.

Comment: Can you provide us the steps you have taken, the code you use etc? Your question doesn't give us much to get on...

Comment: I have used this  [sample from Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) .I managed to use it to print the page, but I wanted it to include binded data that wouldn't appear. All good so far. Then I tried to take a screenshot of said page (successfully) and print the image. This is where the fun begins. I get an out of range values when it tries to create the preview. Resized the image, resized the preview, coded math to resize the image preview. There must be a simpler way than writing over 600 lines for the printing only.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this sample http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/01/20/Printing-from-MVVM-XAML-Windows-8-Store-apps.aspx - It's still a lot of work though...

Comment: @Depechie this just might work with a little change!Please post it separately so I can mark it as an answer!Thank you very much!!

PS: the project was time sensitive so we made a separate exe file to just print when it sees the "name.jpg" and rename the file after. It still bothers me on a personal level so thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diederik Krols did a very detailed blog post about printing, it's for WinRT but should mostly work for UWP too ( except for margins and layout because that has changed in Win10 UWP )

So take a look at this sample http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/01/20/Printing-from-MVVM-XAML-Windows-8-Store-apps.aspx

It's still a lot of work though...

Comment: Don't mind the work.The other wasn't working at all this is what I needed thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use `RawPrinterHelper` class Please see the example in the following link

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091

Comment: Not supported in windows 10.